# Python,import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'am learning python and i have an issue with importing modules/packages 
Well , i'm trying to make a package that contains some modules but the the thing is: the *.py files are depending on each others 
here is the code of the main .py file

```
import suite_syracuse.altitude as alt
import suite_syracuse.duree_vol as dure
N=int(input("Veuillez rentrer le premier terme de la suite ")) 
print("le numero de la vol est ",N,"\nson altitude est ",alt.Altitude(N))
```

when i run it i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./afficher_vol.py", line 2, in <module>
import suite_syracuse.altitude as alt
File "/home/daly/Workshop/Python/suite_syracuse/altitude.py", line 2, in <module>
import Next
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Next'
```

here is the Package architecture :

```
 Workshop/Python/suite_syracuse:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 **** ****  158 juil. 12 00:36 altitude.py                                                                                                          
-rwxr-xr-x 1 **** ****  151 juil. 12 00:27 duree_vol.py                                                                                                                                                   
-rw-r--r-- 1 **** ****    0 juil. 11 22:28 __init__.py                                                          
-rwxr-xr-x 1 **** ****  109 juil. 12 00:34 Next.py  
-drwxr-xr-x 2 **** **** 4096 juil. 12 00:37 __pycache__
```

and finally the altitude.py file :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import Next
def Altitude(N):
 L=[]
 while Next.suiv(N)!=1:
 L.append(Next.suiv(N)) 
 N=Next.suiv(N)
return max(L)
```

and thank you guys :)

Comment: A very quick fix would be to just put all the code in the same file

Comment: what is the command you're running and where are you running it from?

Comment: @frank  hey farnk thx ,the thing is i rly want to learn how to use packages and modules

Comment: @aydow i'm using terminal and ./ command

Answer (score 1):

i find out wat's wrong , i must put an import as it is a package with

```
import suite_syracuse.Next
```

inkstand of

```
import Next
```

thx anyways :)

Comment: While this will work, I don't think it's what you want to do here. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51295988/908494), or [Intra-package references](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are absolute by default. So, `import Next` is looking for a top-level module named `Next`, and that's not what you want.

But when you're trying to import another module in the same package, you usually don't want an absolute import, you want an import relative to the current package:

```
from . import Next
```

If you do want an absolute import, you need to specify the top-level package (or, for more deeply-nested modules, the whole path) to import it from:

```
from suite_syracuse import Next
```

Or, of course, you can do this:

```
import suite_syracuse.Next
```

… but then you'll have to also change your code to call `suite_syracuse.Next.suiv` instead of just `Next.suiv`.

---

This is all explained under [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in the official tutorial, but it's kind of scattered around all over the chapter. (Most of it is in [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), but you wouldn't find that, or maybe even understand it, without reading half the rest of the chapter first.)

You might find it more useful to read [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), the language change proposal that added the current relative import syntax, which gives a lot of background on the design, and on when and why you'd want to use absolute vs. relative imports.

Comment: got it , thx u man :) 
i got lost in the official documentation , didn't find what i want .